# Expected output is returned but still wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I am trying to solve this problem:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/breaking-best-and-worst-records/problem

I wrote this code:

```js
function breakingRecords(arr) {
    let n = arr.length;
    let best = 0;
    let worst = 100000000; // 10^8 (constraints :. cannot get higher)
    let rec1 = 0; // times broken best
    let rec2 = 0; // times broken worst
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > best) {
            best = arr[i];
            if (i != 0) {
                rec1++;
            }
        } else if (arr[i] < worst) {
            if (i != 0) {
                worst = arr[i];
                rec2++;
            }
        }
    }
    return [rec2, rec1];
}

//And for one test case, I say:

console.log(breakingRecords([3, 4, 21, 36, 10, 28, 35, 5, 24, 42]))
```

The output is `[4, 2]`, which is equal to the expected output (the expected output is `4 2`, but they add the space themselves). But, when I enter this code, my output is shown as `4 0`. I test it in my browser and I still get `[4, 2]`.

[image: Output screenshot]

Can someone explain why this is so, and what I can do to fix it? Refreshing doesn't work, and neither does closing and reopening.

Comment: The expected output is 4 0, not 4 2, according to the site.

Comment: I see. Should probably change it to 'What's wrong with this code?' or something

Comment: You just need to initalize the values `best=worst=arr[0]`, since you have to compare to the first score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, **your code** was wrong. The expected results were `4 0`, but your code returned `4 2`.

That was because of the first iteration. The first match's result is *both* the current best and worst but doesn't count into the score. Your code set it only as the best score (because of the `else if`), but not as the worst.

So, let's treat this as a special case, and `shift` the first element out of the array (we can do that safely, as constraints list that the array must contain at least 1 element):

```js
function breakingRecords(arr) {
    let best;
    let worst;
    best = worst = arr.shift() //Get and remove the first element
    let n = arr.length;
    let recBest = 0;  //Use more descriptive names here
    let recWorst = 0; //...and here as well
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > best) {
            best = arr[i];
            recBest++;
        } else if (arr[i] < worst) {
            worst = arr[i];
            recWorst++;
        }
    }
    return [recBest, recWorst];
}

//And for one test case, I say:

console.log(breakingRecords([3, 4, 21, 36, 10, 28, 35, 5, 24, 42])) //[4, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the values to the first score for comparison.

```js
function breakingRecords(arr) {
    let n = arr.length;
    let best = 0;
    let worst = 100000000; // 10^8 (constraints :. cannot get higher)
    let rec1 = 0; // times broken best
    let rec2 = 0; // times broken worst
    
    worst = best = arr[0]; // initialize worst and best to first score
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > best) {
            if (i != 0) {
                best = arr[i];
                rec1++;
            }
        } else if (arr[i] < worst) {
            if (i != 0) {
                worst = arr[i];
                rec2++;
            }
        }
    }
    return [rec1, rec2];  // order of records is also wrong?
}

//And for one test case, I say:

console.log(breakingRecords([3, 4, 21, 36, 10, 28, 35, 5, 24, 42]))
```

Comment: Order of records was different because I got confused between 2, 4 and 4, 2. Thank you, the explanation is very simple. This is upvoted now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can run this one

```
function breakingRecords(scores) {
    let best = 0;
    let worst = 0;
    let bestScore = scores[0];
    let worstScore = scores[0];
    const lengthOfData = scores.length;
    for(let i = 1; i < scores.length; i++) {
        if (scores[i] > bestScore) {
            bestScore = scores[i];
            best++;
            continue;
        }
        if (scores[i] < worstScore) {
            worstScore = scores[i]
            worst++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return [best, worst];
}
```